With angular, How to get a number value from HTML to be used in JS for Math operations
I'm very new to angular and I'm having trouble with using values acquired from the HTML side, in simple operations on the JS side.
in the HTML, this is a sample of what I have
which should place values inside the array of numbers
as they're selected.
<input type="radio" value="0" [(ngModel)]="numArray[0]">
<input type="radio" value="1" [(ngModel)]="numArray[0]">

<input type="radio" value="0" [(ngModel)]="numArray[1]">
<input type="radio" value="1" [(ngModel)]="numArray[1]">

<input type="radio" value="0" [(ngModel)]="numArray[2]">
<input type="radio" value="1" [(ngModel)]="numArray[2]">

and then in JS it sums the values of the array like so:
for(let i=0;i<this.phq4_qs.length;i++){
    sum += numArray[i];
}

console.log(`Sum result ${this.sum}`);

but the console in the web page returns a sequence of numbers instead of the actual sum, like "000" instead of "0" or "101" instead of "2".
I would like to know what am I doing wrong, and if there is a better way to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Your JS doesn't seem to be referencing the HTML at all, but it seems to be concatenating strings rather than adding numbers. Try sum += Number(numArray[i];

try [value]="{{0}}" and [value]="{{1}}" Currently your value attribute is default string type, so the string concatenates to a sequence rather than the sum. To calculate the sum, you need to pass value attribute as number type.

@JamesAshok, NOT. The interpolation ({{ }}) is always a string. When you use binding ([``]) Angular takes the value, so the correct is simply: [value]="0". NOTE You can see it if you write {{numArray[0]|json}} -the json show you if is a string or a number. BTW generally you use a "+" to convert a string to number:sum += (+numArray[i]) instead of use Number.

In HTML, the value attribute of an input element specifies the initial value of that element. When you assign value="something", that something will be treated as a literal string regardless of whether you assign a number or Boolean (value="1" or value="true") inside the double quotes.
So, in your code you are assigning numArray[index] to a string ("0" or "1"). When you iterate this array and add its values to the variable sum, you are performing string concatenation rather than integer addition. Therefore, you get the result as "101" (string) instead of 2.
In order to make your code work as intended, you can perform:
1. Integer parsing
By converting the string to an integer before adding it to sum. There are a number of ways to do that.
Using Number() constructor:
sum += Number(numArray[i])

Using unary operator:
sum += +(numArray[i])

Using parseInt() method:
sum += parseInt(numArray[i])

2. Angular's property binding
Since you are using Angular, you can take advantage of Angular's property binding as well. Instead of assigning value="1", you can put value inside square brackets and assign it as [value]="1". Now Angular will consider the content inside the double quotes as an expression rather than a literal string. It will evaluate the expression and assign the value of the expression to the value attribute. In this case, the expression 1 will evaluate to integer 1. Hence integer 1 will be assigned as the value of the input element. Then you can iterate through the array and directly use the + operator to perform integer addition on the array elements.
sum += numArray[i]

